# how to install boost to the VS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, installation

I've almost completely installed Boost, but I have a problem with how to set my path to Boost in *Tools->options->projects->VC++ Directories*.

I've written the path to include files and libraries (my folder contains two subfolders, `lib` and `include`), but when I try to use Boost with
`#include boost/regex.hpp`, I got this linking error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_36.lib
```

Could you please tell me how to install Boost correctly for Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [Boost Installer](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) by the Boost consulting group.

Comment: @Gili: thanks for the notice. This just goes to show, once again, that changing links sucks and that Cool Links Don’t Change™.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the Visual Studio 2008 Feature pack. It adds many of the features that have only been available from Boost until now, the features that are part of the C++ TR1.

Answer (score 2):

Also checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289909/boost-137) for instructions on how to build Boost yourself.