# Trying to get rid of a c++ boost warning

Tags: c++, boost

Whenever I include boost in my project I get a million of these warnings.  Does anyone know how I can get rid of the warnings?

> ../depends\boost/config/abi_prefix.hpp(19)
>   : warning C4103:
>   'depends\boost\config\abi_prefix.hpp'
>   : alignment changed after including
>   header, may be due to missing #pragma
>   pack(pop)

I know I can do a #pragma to disable the warning, but I'd like to know the reason for these warnings.

Comment: Just to clarify, the error goes away when you don't include the abi_prefix.hpp header?

Comment: It's a aprt of boost, and the header is included by a bunch of other boost headers.

Comment: Just stumble at this page: http://www.ffuts.org/blog/boostthread-triggers-warning-c4103-in-microsoft-vi/ For me it resolve all the warning messages. Snagar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that boost doesn't push/pop these pragmas in every file that needs data to be packed. They #include a separate file which does the push (abi_prefix.hpp), and then another (abo_suffix.hp) afterwards which does the pop.

That allows them to reuse the same #pragma pack code everywhere, which is handy as it may vary between compilers.

It's perfectly safe though. The #pragma push is followed by a pop, it's just included from a different file. So you should probably just disable that error.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd get that from the #pragma pack directive in config/abi/msvc_prefix.hpp.  It indicates that your project's default packing is not 8.  That's pretty unusual, is this intentional?  Bugs due to packing differences can be a bit tricky to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get rid of this warning.

You need to edit the file boost_1_**\boost\config\user.hpp and uncomment the line with BOOST_DISABLE_ABI_HEADERS

So you should be defining in this file:

```
#define BOOST_DISABLE_ABI_HEADERS
```

Once that is done, just [build with bjam like you normally would](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289909/boost-137).

**Please see comments below for dangers of this solution**

Comment: Doesn't that mean it never enables packing? Seems like that could introduce a lot of fun errors.

Comment: It is safe if you are using your own boost dlls only or if you are statically linking.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410981/what-harm-can-come-from-defining-boostdisableabiheaders-when-compiling-boost#410992

Comment: Still seems like a lot of trouble (and a source of potential bugs) to go to just to eliminate a warning. I think you'd be better off just disabling that warning. With the #define, if you compile boost with just slightly different compiler flags than the rest of your code, fun crashes ensue.

Comment: You should also ensure that all projects that you use have the same build settings.  Exmaple if you have a .lib.  I agree with you overall though, I'm going to re-compile without this define.  I'll keep this post though for history so people can see.