# How to set up Boost?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, boost

How to set up boost in visual studio?

Don't understand how to make this library to work.

Each time out errors when compiling programms.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The very first thing your fingers should do after typing "errors" is to continue by typing out what the errors are, including the **exact** error messages you're getting. We can't see your screen (or code) from here, and so we only know what you tell us in your question. If you don't give us the information, we can't help you. Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), especially the part about how to ask a question better to improve your chances of getting an answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Also, searching here before asking would have given you [how to install boost to the VS 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256109/how-to-install-boost-to-the-vs-2008), which might have helped solve your problem without even asking the question. :)

Comment: I apologize for this issue, yet not understand it at all :)
Ken, thank you for what still answered my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Boost consists of quite a few libraries - some of them need to be pre-built, while others don't. Besides, you have to set "path" in VisualStudio, to let it know where Boost headers reside. Take a look at the ["Getting Started" section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost).